# Curvature function as a random variable with uniform distribution

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability, riemannian-geometry, probability-distributions, curvature

Let $(S,g)$ be a Riemannian  surface. Then the curvature function $\kappa: S\to \mathbb{R}$ can be counted as a random variable. So it produces a probability density function
$f_g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Similarly every Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ introduces a probability density function $f_g$ associated with  the scalar curvature $R:M\to \mathbb{R}$ as a random variable.

**Question:** Can one equip  a compact surface  $S$ with a Riemannian metric $g$ such that the resulting probability distribution be a uniform distribution, i.e the density function $f_g$
be a constant function ? What about the case of Riemannian manifolds, namely dimension greater than 2 ? If the answer is yes, can we choose an analytic Riemannian metric with the above mentioned property ? (The distribution associated to the curvature function be uniform.)

Comment: @DenisSerre, will you revert your edits? As I see it, deleting the word "would" is bad grammar, and inserting spaces before the question marks is bad punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

Any surface, compact or otherwise, admits a metric with constant scalar curvature, so we can always find metrics with uniform density. Furthermore, any compact manifold admits a metric of constant scalar curvature in its conformal class, by the solution to the Yamabe problem.  On the other hand, the scalar curvature measures the deviation of the size of small geodesic balls of radius $\varepsilon$ around a point compared to corresponding balls in Euclidean space,  but this deviation has size $\varepsilon^{n+2}$. As such, if the scalar curvature is non-constant, its induced measure is non-uniform.

**Edit with more details:**

Here is a more detailed derivation of why it is necessary for the scalar curvature to be constant in order for the induced measure to be uniform.

Suppose $p \in M$ is a point with scalar curvature $S$. The scalar curvature satisfies the identity:

$$ \frac{\operatorname{Vol}(B_\varepsilon(p) \subset M)}{\operatorname{Vol}\left(B_\varepsilon(0)\subset {\mathbb R}^n\right)} =
  1 - \frac{S}{6(n + 2)}\varepsilon^2 + O\left(\varepsilon^4\right),$$
so if we consider a ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around $p$, we have that the average scalar curvature in this ball satisfies the following.

$$\int_{B_\varepsilon(p)} S \, d \mu = \operatorname{Vol}(B_\varepsilon(p)) ( S(p) +O(\varepsilon) ),  $$
where the error depends on the gradient of the curvature. Combining this estimate with the previous one, we have that

$$\int_{B_\varepsilon(p)} S \, d \mu = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\bigl(\tfrac n2 + 1\bigr)} \varepsilon^n \left( 1 - \frac{S}{6(n + 2)}\varepsilon^2 + O\left(\varepsilon^4\right) \right) \left( S(p) +O(\varepsilon) \right).$$

Simplifying this, we find that

\begin{eqnarray}\int_{B_\varepsilon(p)} S \, d \mu 
& = & S(p) \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\bigl(\tfrac n2 + 1\bigr)} \varepsilon^n +O( \varepsilon^{n+1}) \\
& = & S(p) \operatorname{Vol}\left(B_\varepsilon(0)\subset {\mathbb R}^n\right) +O(\varepsilon^{n+1}).
\end{eqnarray}

As such, if we have two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ whose scalar curvatures are not equal, by taking  balls around each point which are sufficiently small, we see that the average value of $S$ in the first ball is essentially $S(p_1)$ whereas the average value in the second ball is $S(p_2)$.  Here, "sufficiently small" depends on the $C^1$ norm of the curvature, so I haven't tried to make it explicit.

The key point here is that in the first equation, the scalar curvature only appears in the second order term, which is why it is negligible in the volume estimate.

Comment: I think the question is asking about a distribution that is uniform between some $a$ and $b$ — i.e. for a manifold where, whenever $x<b$, the area with curvature between $a$ and $x$ is proportional to $x-a$.

Comment: That's correct. The observation about the geodesic balls shows that in order for the measure to be uniform, the scalar curvature must be constant.

Comment: @MattF. Yes  that s is my question. but the answer by Gabe K says that it is impossible. The random variable is constant.

Comment: @MattF. Let  the image of the curvature is $[a,b]$ and the curvature has uniform distribution. According to the formula  $log (V_{g}(\epsilon)(p)/V_{E}(\epsilon)p)  \to k(p)$ how can we get a contradiction?

Comment: Thank you very much  and my previous +1  for your  attention to my question and your  answer.I would appreciate if you explain the details. I thought about your answer but i do not get the idea how to conclude the imposibility of a uniform distribution.

Comment: @AliTaghavi I've edited the answer to provide more detail why it is necessary for the scalar curvature to be constant.

Comment: @GabeK, how does this use the uniformity of the distribution?

Comment: @MattF. In order for the distribution to be uniform, we must have that $\int_{B_\epsilon(p)} S d \mu = C Vol({B_\epsilon(p)})$ for some constant $C$. This calculation shows that if the scalar curvature is not constant, this is not the case because the integral is $S(p) Vol({B_\epsilon(p)}) + O(\varepsilon^{n+1})$

Comment: @GabeK, I think an estimate for the needed $\epsilon$ in terms of $C$ would convince me.

Comment: @MattF. The $C$ in the above formula comes from the definition of a distribution being uniform, so this identity must hold for all $\varepsilon$. If you want a more explicit estimate on the $O(\varepsilon^{n+1})$ term, from the first integral identity in the answer, you can replace the $O(\varepsilon)$ term by $\pm \|\nabla S \|_\infty \varepsilon$. Going through the rest of the calculation, this shows that the $O(\varepsilon^{n+1})$ term at the end can be bounded by $ \pm \|\nabla S \|_\infty \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\bigl(\tfrac n2 + 1\bigr)} \varepsilon^{n+1}$

Comment: It's easy to miss the forest for the trees in the calculation, but if you think about what the scalar curvature is actually measuring, it should give some intuition for why this must be the case.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. but I am not convinced yet that this is the definition of uniformicity.

Comment: But I agree with the first comment by  @MattF.   What is  a relation to the initial definition of uniform distribution?

Comment: @AliTaghavi A distribution $f d \mu$ is uniform with respect to a measure $\mu$ if and only if it satisfies the identity $\int_E f d \, \mu = C \mu(E) $ for all measurable sets $E$. In other words, you require the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{ f d \mu}{d \mu}$ to be a constant value $C$.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple example, consider the curve $y=f(x)$, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, with measure given by the arclength $ds=(1+f'^2)^{1/2}dx$. The curvature is $\kappa=f''(1+f'^2)^{-3/2}$, for a uniform distribution we want $d\kappa=cds$, with $c>0$. This gives for the curve the differential equation
$$(1+f'(x))f'''(x)-3f'(x)f''(x)^2=c(1+f'(x))^3.$$
Here is a numerical solution for $c=1$.

[image]

Comment: I think the question begins with dimension 2, but this is a good answer for the simpler 1-dimensional case.

Comment: The question is about the curvature of a Riemannian metric. The curvature of a plane curve is not the curvature of any Riemannian metric, because every Riemannian metric in dimension 1 is flat: the curvature tensor is a 2-form valued in endomorphisms of the tangent bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, too long for a comment.

Consider the torus, $[-\pi,\pi]^2$, with coordinates $t$ and $u$ and metric
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & (9+\sin t)^2
\end{pmatrix}
Then the scalar curvature is
$$\frac{2\sin t}{9+\sin t}$$
and the pdf of that scalar curvature is
$$\frac{18}{\pi(2-w)^2\sqrt{1+4w}\sqrt{1-5w}}\ \text{ on }\ \frac{-1}{4}\le w\le \frac15$$
or graphically

[image]

This is not uniform, but might be encouraging.